# unity Editor Dialgue box is not closing

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have created a DialogueBox on Unity using the code below.

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Provided Data is Wrong","Please Correct the Erors","Retry");
```

Now, I dont know how to close it? Even the `x` button on the top right corner won't close it.
What should I do?